# Why does a function obtained from `.bind(...)` have no `.prototype` property?

Tags: javascript, bind

Consider the following use case for creating two classes `Point` and `YAxisPoint`:

```js
function Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
Point.prototype.toString = function() { 
  return `${this.x},${this.y}`; 
};

var p = new Point(1, 2);
var YAxisPoint = Point.bind(null, 0);
var axisPoint = new YAxisPoint(5);

console.log(p.toString()); // '1,2'
console.log(axisPoint.toString()); // '0,5'
```

Executing this code in the browser yields the correct results. Now let's say I want to override the `toString` function for `YAxisPoint` constructor:

```
YAxisPoint.prototype.toString = function() { return 'override'; }
var newAxisPoint = new YAxisPoint(5);
console.log(newAxisPoint.toString()); // 'override'
```

Executing this code in the browser yields:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'toString' of undefined

**Question 1**

Why is the prototype for `YAxisPoint` is undefined?

I really don't get it. If I add the following polyfill it works as expected.

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== 'function') {
      // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
      // internal IsCallable function
      throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');
    }

    var aArgs   = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
        fToBind = this,
        fNOP    = function() {},
        fBound  = function() {
          return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP
                 ? this
                 : oThis,
                 aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };

    if (this.prototype) {
      // Function.prototype doesn't have a prototype property
      fNOP.prototype = this.prototype; 
    }
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
  };
```

**Question 2**

Is there a bug in the browser implementations for bind? I tried this in Opera, Safari, Chrome, and Firefox and they all have the same problem.

Here is a [link](https://repl.it/Luro/5) to a code that you can run to test.

The polyfill in this sandbox is commented out. You can uncomment that to validate.

Comment: You can do this... `function YAxisPoint(y) { return new (Point.bind.call(Point, null, 0, y)) }`, but seems kind of hacky. Why not just declare another constructor?

Comment: Thanks for the quick followup @elclanrs. But what I'm trying to figure out is why the native `bind` implementation is not honoring the prototype object. You can see that just adding the polyfill make it work just fine. Thoughts?

Comment: Bound functions are not regular functions, they are some sort of special object in JavaScript, but I'm not sure why that happens, I'm curious too.

Comment: Cool. Yeah I'm just trying to understand the bind implementation and what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: So, aside from a curiosity, I don't see why you would try to implement things this way.  Why not use one of the standard prototypal inheritance methods that are common in JS?

Comment: Yeah, this is just for curiosity. I had no idea how bind was implemented when you had to take `new` into account. It took this example from the MDN site. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind.

Comment: You can see in the polyfill that the `this.prototype` is being transferred to the `fBound` function, which makes sense to me. I just don't know why the browser implementation is not doing the same.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the differences in the polyfill from the MDN site and the browser implementation for bind function

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: the expected results are described beside the `console.log` calls. You can also run the repl.it script (the link for that is also in the question).

Comment: What is the purpose of `var YAxisPoint = Point.bind(null, 0);`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155733/discussion-between-alan-souza-and-guest271314).

Answer (score -1):

The expected result can be achieved by using `Reflect.construct()` and setting `.toString()` at `.__proto__` of `axisPoint`

```js
function Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

Point.prototype.toString = function() { 
  return `${this.x},${this.y}`; 
};

var p = new Point(1, 2);
var axisPoint = Reflect.construct(Point.bind(null /* Point */, 0), [5]);

console.log(p.toString()); // '1,2'
console.log(axisPoint.toString()); // '0,5'

axisPoint.__proto__.toString = function() { 
  return 'override'; 
}

console.log(axisPoint.toString());
```